# Como transformar uma função assíncrona em síncrona?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, assincronismo

Tenho uma função assíncrona e gostaria de que ela se tornasse síncrona, pois estando assíncrona ela está enviando os dados para o cliente antes mesmo de concluir as etapas necessárias, segue código:

```
imap.once('ready', function () {
    openInbox(function (err, box) {
        if (err) throw err;
        imap.search(['ALL'], function (err, results) {
            if (err) throw err;
            let arquivo = imap.fetch(results, {bodies: ''});
            arquivo.on('message', function (msg, num) {
                msg.on('body', function (stream, info) {
                    simpleParser(stream)
                        .then(mail => {
                            email = {
                                id: num,
                                remetente: mail.from.text,
                                destinatario: mail.to.text,
                                assunto: mail.subject,
                                texto: mail.text
                            };
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err)
                        });
                });
                msg.on('end', function () {
                    console.log(num + ' concluído!');
                })
            });
            arquivo.on('error', function (err) {
                console.log('Erro em arquivo.once: ' + err)
            });
            arquivo.on('end', function () {
                console.log('Concluído!')
            })
        })
    })
});
imap.once('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Erro no Imap.once' + err);
});
imap.once('end', function () {
    console.log('Encerrado!');
});
imap.connect();
```

Como tornar essa função assíncrona?? Qual o lugar correto para colocar o response??

Obs.: Servidor HapiJS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sendo que `arquivo.on('message'` chama a função *N* vezes, 1 por email, então podes ir criando Promises e inserir num array e depois quando `arquivo.on('end'` for chamado podes esperar que todas as promises estejam prontas e usar esses mails.

O código seria assim:

```
imap.search(['ALL'], function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let arquivo = imap.fetch(results, {
        bodies: ''
    });
    const emails = []; // <--- aqui vais juntando Promises
    arquivo.on('message', function(msg, num) {
        const compilador = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {
                simpleParser(stream)
                    .then(mail => {
                        resolve({
                            id: num,
                            remetente: mail.from.text,
                            destinatario: mail.to.text,
                            assunto: mail.subject,
                            texto: mail.text
                        })
                    })
                    .catch(reject);
            });
            msg.on('end', function() {
                console.log(num + ' concluído!');
            })
        });
        emails.push(compilador);
    });
    arquivo.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('Erro em arquivo.once: ' + err)
    });
    arquivo.on('end', function() {
        Promise.all(emails).then(array => { // <--- aqui vais vai verificar/esperar que todas estão prontas
            console.log(array);
            console.log('Concluído!');
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente... 
Muito obrigado